# gdb within emacs on Windows

Tags: emacs, gdb, cygwin, dot-emacs

I'm running Emacs 22.3 in Windows.  Earlier today I had gdb working within Emacs just fine.  I was installing QT4 and during the installation it asked me to uninstall MSYS which I quickly clicked through not thinking about things.  I think I had gdb installed with the MSYS package and Emacs was using that, but I'm not completely sure.  Now when I run the following I get an error in the mini-buffer.

```
M-x gdb
"Searching for program: no such file or directory, gdb"
```

I tried to add the path "`C:\cygwin\bin`" to the Emacs load-path with this code but I still get the same error.

```
(message "Adding cygwin/bin to load path.")
(add-to-list 'load-path "c:/cygwin/bin")
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably adjust your system path to point it where you have gdb installed.

Comment: Thanks, this works on my laptop so I'll be trying it in the morning at work.

Comment: Adding the C:\cygwin\bin directory to my system path worked & now I can run it within emacs.  I'm running into another problem where my breakpoints are working but gdb isn't showing my code in another window.  I'm going to post another question about it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using /cygdrv/c/cygwin/bin