# gdb not showing code within emacs on Windows

Tags: emacs, cygwin, dot-emacs

I asked a question just yesterday which caused this new issue.  [gdb within emacs on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424231/gdb-within-emacs-on-windows)

Basically I was installing a QT sdk which asked me to uninstall MSYS which I did & I hosed my emacs/gdb interaction.

Here is the gdb_init file that I'm using.  Before the uninstall of MSYS this worked fine.  Now after it, the breakpoints are working but I am not getting my code in another window with the little red dot on the left margin for a breakpoint.

```
file ~/../sandbox/trunk/current-win32/debug-bin/sm.exe
dir ~/../sandbox/trunk/src/mgr/view
dir ~/../sandbox/trunk/src/mgr/view/appstatus
dir ~/../sandbox/trunk/src/mgr/controller
break widget.cpp:176
break book.cpp:72
break TcpClient.cpp:660
break mainwidget.cpp:1474
```

The steps I'm running in emacs

```
M-x gdb 
source ~/gdb_init 
run 
(It will break but not give me the code along with the breakpoint)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was using the Cygwin version of gdb and had that in my system PATH.  For some reason that didn't work out and I was getting errors in gdb within Emacs.  Once I installed MSYS(mingw) & the gdb install on their download page and put that in my system PATH then I was back up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem: windows emacs, cygwin gdb, and the source buffer did not update with the "=>" pointer to show the code location.   Downloaded mingw gdb.exe from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/OldFiles/and selected that gdb with M-x gdb and it worked perfectly.